# C# Replace Resource File Values

Tags: c#, resources, resx

I'm not sure how to ask this question, but hopefully someone will understand and please feel free to correct my lack of terminology.

I'm using resource files to display the website in various languages. There's a section in a sentence that is driven by data from a DB, which we have a method for, and grabs it's resource from a **local** resource file.

Below is what our `default.aspx` file looks like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello,</h1>
        <p><asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: PersonalAttentionParagraph %>" /></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The local resource file contains:

```
...
<data name="PersonalAttentionParagraph" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Blah... 14:1 ...more blah!.</value>
</data>
...
```

That `14:1` value needs to come from a function:

```
string GetValue(){
    return "14:1";
}
```

*Question:* How do you properly create a replace functionality calling a resource file in this manner?

I was thinking of replacing the `Resource` file value `14:1` with `@@VALUE@@` and then calling a `Replace()` on it, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way of doing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly common to put "blah... {0} .. more blah" in the resource file.  When you use it, just use string.format(yourResourceString,someComputedValue.ToString()).

Comment: Omg. Totally forgot about that! I’ll test it tomorrow. FYI project is still C#5 if it matters. Do I have to change how I call the resource itself through that literal?

Comment: Should be fine.  String.Format has been around forever.  No need to change how you get the string from the resource file as long as you wind up with a string.

Comment: Dan, I'm getting an error stating: `The server tag is not well formed.` I updated the server tag to `<asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: string.Format(PersonalAttentionParagraph, "10:1") %>" />` and `<asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$ string.Format(Resources: PersonalAttentionParagraph, "10:1") %>" />`

Comment: I should specify this resource file is `local`, not `global`